# magit: squash commits in feature branch, but ability to unravel later if needed

Tags: magit

Does magit offer a way to squash a bunch of commits, but preserve some sort of record
of the micro commits - should you need to step through them the next day.

Answer (score 2):

Just create a branch before squashing.

In magit:

1. Optional: copy the name of the current branch (you can find it on the first line of the `*magit*` buffer).
2. `b n` to create a new branch. Paste the name of the current branch if it helps you, and give the new branch a unique name (e.g. with a `-detailed-history` suffix).

(But better yet, don't squash. A detailed commit history is useful and squashing rarely has any benefit.)

Answer (score 1):

Magit does not provide any feature specifically for this use-case. It does however expose a `git` feature that can be used in this and other situations when you have to recover some discarded work: the reflog.

The reflog commands are available from the same popup menu as the log commands: <kbd>l</kbd>.

Search the web for information about what the reflog is and how to use it.

While viewing a reflog you can use <kbd>l o RET</kbd> to view the *log* for the reflog entry at point.

Comment: The reflog won't be preserved for long and can't be pushed. Why not give the current commit history a persistent name, i.e. a branch?

Comment: It all depends on the use-case. So both answers makes sense and complete each other.